# Differentiating composite function

Tags: calculus, functions

Can anyone say the basic formula for the differentiation of the composite functions? Is it similar to chain rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composite function rule or the chain rule, same thing, state that if we have $$f(x)=h(g(x))$$ then $$f'(x) = h'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

Edit: To clarify, the "formula" for differentiating a composite function is the chain rule.

Edit2: To further clarify, $h(g(x))$ is the same thing as $(h \circ g)(x)$. Just different notation.

Comment: And another one, is h (g(x)) and (h○g)(x) similar?

Comment: They are the same thing, see my edit! If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted by pressing the green tick on the left! :)

Comment: Thanks @chickenP, yes I noticed the edit later..and yes I would surely accept your answer..not accepting it will prove me as brainless!

Comment: And take note of me..If you are really 14 years old and you are doing calculus of high level...you are one of a kind

Comment: Haha, glad I helped! :)